# how to download a lot image using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i'm using filesaver as `save as` in browser...this code works well on any website but there's a problem when i use this script it only download just 9 image...so i wonder what is wrong with this code..

```
function down() {
    var loc_gal = document.getElementsByClassName('detail-gallery-list')[0]
    var loc_url = loc_gal.getElementsByClassName('detail-gallery-item');

    var dump_url = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < loc_url.length; i++) {
        var dump = loc_url[0].querySelector('img').src;
        var splitname = dump.split('1.');
        var filename = splitname[0]+[i]+'.webp';
        // store url from filename into the array dump_url
        dump_url.push(filename)
    }
```

i have 2 different method to access array

1. this method works well to access array and use the index to get link from `dump_url` but have a same issue it only download 9 image if more then that it just only duplicate each file has been downloaded

```
    for (let x in dump_url){
        setTimeout(() => {
            saveAs(dump_url[x],'0.webp');
          }, 2000)
    }
```

2. same issue only download 9 image

```
dump_url.forEach(element => saveAs(element,'0.webp'))
```

i got the same result from 2 different menthod

[result of the 2 method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5dRf.jpg)

What is wrong with my code ? The page have more than 20 image.

**Note : I use Tempermonkey to run my script**

Comment: Any error in  the console  maybe ? Maybe something crashes with the 10th url ?

Comment: console.log(loc_url.length) and check its length if length is 9 or greater.

Comment: @Peterrabbit there's no error with the 10th url in the console...i have been check the url from ```dump_url``` using for loop...is work well it show 100 lines url, when i check the validation url using python and it gives status 200 it mean's ok

Comment: Show the html please

Comment: @Konrad what kind html you mean ? i just write full JS code to download image and i run the script using tempermonkey

Comment: I guess that `loc_gal.getElementsByClassName('detail-gallery-item')` just returns 9 elements, so I wanted to see the html if there are more than 9

Comment: @Konrad (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XANDER001/Materi/main/html/result%2B2.png)

Comment: So maybe `var splitname = dump.split('1.');
        var filename = splitname[0]+[i]+'.webp';` is wrong

Comment: @Konrad no...it's perfectly works...i have been copy the result of ```filename``` and store it into the csv after that check status ```requests``` using python...it gives ```200```